# Pg-promise: proper way of returning result of query

Tags: node.js, express, asynchronous, pg-promise

I want to check whether a username is already in use using `pg-promise`.

I use the following query:

```
this.db.one('SELECT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM users WHERE username = $1)', username);
```

I am trying to encapsulate this query inside a function that simply returns true if the username exists, false if not.

Something like:

```
existsUsername(username){
  this.db.one('SELECT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM users WHERE username = $1)', username)
         .then(data => {
           if(data.exists == true){
             return true;
           } else {
             return false;
           }
         });
}
```

That I can simply use like so:

```
if(db.users.existsUsername(username)){
  // this username is already taken
}
```

However the if condition is assessed before the query finishes, resulting in an undefined variable.

What is the proper way of returning the result of a query?

EDIT: the outer caller performs multiple async checks and returns whether the user is valid or not:

```
function signUp(username, email, ...){
  // perform username existence check existsUser(username)

  // perform email existence check existsEmail(username)

  // ...

  // if everything OK, put user in DB
}
```

Comment: U seems to forgot return in existsUsername

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Simplest way of doing it:

```
existsUsername(username) {
  return this.db.oneOrNone('SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = $1 LIMIT 1', username, a => !!a);
}
```

And then use it:

```
db.users.existsUsername(username)
   .then(exists => {
      // exists - boolean
   })
   .catch(error => {
   });
```

You cannot do things like `if(db.users.existsUsername(username))`, that's mixing up synchronous code with asynchronous. But you can do `if(await db.users.existsUsername(username))`, if ES7 syntax is available to you.

---

And if you have three independent functions like that (`checkUserName`, `checkEmail`, `checkWhateverElse`), and want to execute them all, here's the best way to do it:

```
db.task(t => {
   return t.batch([checkUserName(t), checkEmail(t), checkWhateverElse(t)]);
})
.then(data => {
    // data = result of the batch operation;
})
.catch(error => {
   // error
});
```

The same with ES7 syntax:

```
db.task(async t => {
   const a = await checkUserName(t);
   const b = await checkEmail(t);
   const c = await checkWhateverElse(t);
   return {a, b, c};
})
.then(data => {
    // data = {a, b, c} object;
})
.catch(error => {
   // error
});
```

**Note:** Each of those functions is expected to execute queries against `t` - task context, in order to share the connection.

Answer (score 1):

You can't use async operation in sync way, you need to rewrite the code that checks if user exists in async way as well. I.e.:

```
// returns a promise 
function existsUsername(username){
   return this.db.one('SELECT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM users WHERE username = $1)', username);
}
```

And next use it in app in a way like

```
db.users.existsUsername(username)
   .then( data => {
      data.exists ? handleUserExistsAsync() : handleUserNotExistsAsync();
   })
   .catch( err => {
      // some err occurs, db fail or something
      // however, you can catch it in an upper level
   });
```

EDIT: Using [Promise.all](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all) for multiple tasks, may have performance and connection issues (as Vitaly mentioned).

It's better to use [db.batch](http://vitaly-t.github.io/pg-promise/Task.html#batch) inside [db.task](https://github.com/vitaly-t/pg-promise/#tasks)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But then as I have multiple such queries (existsUsername, existsEmail etc), how do I know that all the async operations are finished and that I can move on to the return statement of the caller?

Comment: They finished in callback you passed to `.then( data => { ...query done with data... })`

Comment: I edited my post to better reflect what I had in mind. I meant to say I need some sort of barrier that guarantees all callbacks have finished before the outer caller can finish.

Comment: Yeah, use Promise.all([checkUserName(), checkEmail(), checkWhateverElse()]).then( arrayOfChecksResults => // check that arrayIs ok, and save user )

Comment: Beside Promise.all there are other methods to manage bunch of promises, you can check which one is preferable for you

Comment: That's exactly what I was looking for! Thanks!

Comment: Please note that http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/getting-started.html buebird promise have better perfarmance

Comment: You should never use `Promise.all` with the database methods, as they all end up executing against separate connections, and that's not good for performance. See [Chaining Queries](https://github.com/vitaly-t/pg-promise/wiki/Chaining-Queries). Instead, you should use a task with a `batch`.